# How do I call a method taking a union of string literals when I have a normal string?

Tags: typescript

In the following TypeScript function declaration, the `alignment` parameter type is a set of unioned literals.

```
function printText(s: string, alignment: "left" | "right" | "center") {
  // ...
}
```

According to the [docs on literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), a variable of type `string` is not assignable to `alignment` because strictly speaking it's not of type `"left" | "right" | "center"`.

The documentation says to use a type assertion like so:

```
printText("Test", printerConfig.textAlignment as "left");
```

And this would also work:

```
const printerConfig = { textAlignment: "left" } as const;

printText("Test", printerConfig.textAlignment);
```

Now imagine:

1. The `printText` function was in a library and I could not change it.
2. My code had been passed a `printerConfig` object or it'd read it from a JSON config file.
3. That its `textAlignment` property was of type `string`.

How can I call the `printText` function?

Comment: Hint: How would you do it in JavaScript? The solution is basically the same in TypeScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd think you would not want to call `printText` if the `alignment` was not a sensible value - what if the caller of your code passed a bad config object, or the JSON was badly formatted? You'd probably want to throw an error before calling `printText`.

Narrow the type of the `textAlignment` before passing it. If it's not the right type, throw an error.

```
// have checks of textAlignment narrow this new variable
const { textAlignment } = printerConfig;
if (textAlignment !== 'left' && textAlignment !== 'right' && textAlignment !== 'center') {
  throw new Error(`Invalid textAlignment: ${textAlignment}`);
}
printText("Test", textAlignment);
```

Comment: This is what I thought. It's interesting because designing your method to take a union effectively passes the buck back to the caller to write the checking code. That could be perceived as annoying additional hassle for consumers of the function, depending on their point of view.

Comment: Yes, that's how it should be. If you design a function, it's up to the caller of your function to call it with the rules you set out. If your function is passed values it can't make sense of (given the clear rules it's layed out), only the caller has the ability to know what to do in such a situation.

Comment: If you're doing this check a lot, you can use an assertion function. `function assertValidAlignment(str: string): asserts str is 'left'|'right'|'center' { ... }`

Comment: @LukePuplett "*That could be perceived as annoying additional hassle for consumers of the function, depending on their point of view.*"  this is literally already the norm. We could be using strings for everything. Yet we use numbers, or booleans, for example. And in a strongly typed system nobody seems to complain about the hassle of making sure they call `takeANumberAndDoSomethingWithIt(n)` and have to make sure `n` is a proper number. And stuff like `setBirthYear(-5)` throwing an error is also unexpected when well documented that years should be positive.